# python xlwings AutoFill without formatting

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

Please help with the following example problem which demonstrates the issue:

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


wb = xw.Book()
ws = wb.sheets("Sheet1")

#Sample data
ws.range("A1").value = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["A", "B"], data = np.zeros((6, 2))).values

#Border
ws.range("A3:B3").api.Borders(9).LineStyle = 1 #9 is for a bottom border

#Create value in cell A1 to autofill
ws.range("A1").value = 1
#Autofill
ws.range("A1").api.AutoFill(ws.range("A1:A6").api, 0) #The border in column A is removed :(
```

I've tried different variations of the last argument for the autofill method (ie. instead of having '0'),
such as:

type = AutoFillType.xlFillValues

AutoFillType.xlFillValues

type = xlFillValues

Various numbers (guessing) ie. 1, 2, 3..

Comment: Solved! Folks! I mentioned that I guessed using various numbers as the last argument, the correct number is 4! ie. ws.range("A1").api.AutoFill(ws.range("A1:A6").api, 4) will fill without formatting!

Answer (score 0):

The last line (AutoFill) works fine. You'll have to look up the value for the specific XlAutoFillType you want from the [MSDN reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlautofilltype). For example, if you want to have "xlFillValues" use:

```
ws.range("A1").api.AutoFill(ws.range("A1:A6").api, 4)
```

Or you can import constants as described [here](https://github.com/pybokeh/jupyter_notebooks/blob/master/xlwings/Excel_Formatting.ipynb).